# <img> within anchor not displaying properly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, anchor

I am testing my site on mobile, tablet, and cross-broswer.  I have noticed that my images that are inside of an anchor tag are displaying improperly. This only happens on FireFox.  Has anyone had any issues with this?  I am attaching two images...the first is chrome, the second is FireFox.

[image: Chrome]

[image: FireFox]

The html is:

```
<a href="" class="btn body-button">Learn More<img src="/sites/all/themes/merge/img/arrow.png" /></a>
```

And the SCSS:

```
.body-button{ width: auto;display: block; @include open-bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px; border-radius: 0px; opacity: .9; text-transform:uppercase; color:white; background: $blue; padding: 15px;}

.body-button img{ float: right; width: 9px; height: 15px;display: inline-block; }
```

Does anyone know why Firefox does this?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with your html and css please.

Comment: your image height is 15px but your line height is 14px.

Comment: sure, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/jbarbermerge/0s54ruyq/

Comment: It would better if we could **"fiddle"** with your code. ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jbarbermerge/0s54ruyq/

Comment: Martin, changing the line-height does not fix/effect this problem

Comment: Try this out http://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/0s54ruyq/1/

Comment: @user3633970 I can't duplicate your problem. I put a real image in your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/0s54ruyq/2/ - but the result looks the same in Chrome and Firefox.